# copy mount from one server to another

Tags: linux, mount

I'm trying to copy the mount point from `server1` to `server2`.

So I copy the file, which I found in `/etc/fstab`, and did `mount -a`.

It gives me the following error:

```
mount: special device /dev/dX/dY does not exist
```

So I look at `/dev/dX/dY` in `server1` and it has a link to `../d1`.

When I did `ll` in `../` in server1, I found the next statement:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    num,   0  May 06 06:22 d1
```

What should I do in order to complete the mount process?

Comment: What you did doesn't make much sense, except for things like remote mounts (NFS/CIFS). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Post the real output, with the actual numbers and names. It's hard to tell what you've replaced by metavariables and what you've kept as is. Copy-paste the output of commands like `ls -l`.

Comment: Something is missing in your question. What are you trying to do? Did you put the disk from one machine into another machine? Are you trying to copy files over the network?